# How to create externally unmodifiable variable?

Tags: c++

I'm developing simple simulation library and came across problem, where I have simulation `Time` variable, which **shouldn't** be modifiable by API user (programmer) at any circumstances (just provide information about simulation time), but **should be modifiable** by simulation library, so it cannot be constant.

This is what I came up with yet but it seems a little bit tricky to me

```
double simTime;                // Internal time, modified by library
const double& Time = simTime;  // Time info provided for programmer in API
```

Is there an approach for this without `const double&`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of `const double &` you can change your API to provide a function `double getTime();` which returns the value of `simTime`.

Comment: Agreed. Even if it means some extra time to execute the function, this is better in terms of design and separation.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher True - there is a slight overhead because you are calling a function now.

Comment: Maybe. A smart enough compiler may inline or otherwise eliminate it.

Comment: That overhead of function is exactly what I'm trying to avoid :-) but seems like the best solution, tho.

Comment: @FilipKočica Try benchmarking with the function and without to see if it has any negative impact before avoiding it: premature optimisation etc etc.

Comment: @hnefatl Sure, but i dont know which compiler will API user use. It also depends on *what* will user simulate.

Comment: Please note that `getTime()` does not prohibit that external modules modify `simTime`.

Comment: @StephanLechner I agree. I can see your answer addresses this problem.

Comment: @FilipKočica you have to optimize only known critical places. Such optimization seems wrong. Also you will not be able make the variable thread-safe in the future, if you didn't encapsulate it

Comment: @FilipKočica If the function is written inline (as it should be) the compiler will not generate a function call for such a trivial function. My guess is that doing it this way may be more efficient that going through a reference because a reference will require an indirection.

Comment: @Galik It cannot be inlined in the API header, because the implementation will be in the library. Otherwise, if you put the inline implementation in the header, this means you can access the variable in the header (i.e. from user code), which defeats the purpose of encapsulating it in the first place.

Comment: @GeorgiGerganov Why not? What prevents it?

Comment: @Galik Linkage.

Answer (score 5):

I find the `const double&`-solution rather straight forward and elegant, and I don't see any negative side effects.

The only thing is that your library should declare `simTime` either as `static` or in an anonymous namespace such that it cannot be addressed from outside. Otherwise, any `extern double simTime` in any other translation unit would expose `simTime`.

So write...

```
// library.cpp:
static double simTime;
const double &simTimePublic = simTime;

// library.h:
extern const double &simTimePublic;

// userCode.cpp:
#include "library.h"
...
double simTimeCopy = simTimePublic;

// simTimePublic = 1.0; // illegal
```

Comment: This method has disadvantage that I wont be able to use Time, more specifically set time in other modules.

Comment: @Filip Kočica: it is actually about avoiding modicifations of `simTime` in other modules; and there is no way in C++ of distinguishing between "own" modules and modules of other users.

Comment: Ok, but what about operations with the variable inside the library? It will be used as global?

Comment: @VladimirBershov Yes, it is global variable.

Comment: A caveat is that the SIOF is possible with this approach. This can work so long as the reference is used only after main begins. Using it in the initialization of other static objects carries the risk of nasal demons.

Comment: @StoryTeller Are not reference always statically initialized?

Comment: @Oliv - Are they? I lost track with all the changes to static initialization every 3 years.

Comment: @StoryTeller I am going to look for it in the standard. I supposer that because I imagine static reference are just aliasing symbols in the object file.

Comment: @StoryTeller I found nothing clear. I cannot determine if the initializer expression is a constant expression  because in case of direct reference binding, the initializer is not evaluated, and i dont find bullet for that in [expr.const].  On the other hand,  it is possible to bind a refence non type template parameter to any static object, so even if the standard is not clear, I hope compilers behave consistently with this last requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You could even (in a public header) define some *inline* function returning an external variable whose name is long enough to not be easily guessable, e.g.

```
static inline double getTime(void) {
  extern double somelongname_simTime; // don't use that name directly
  return somelongname_simTime;
}
```

indeed, the name `somelongname_simTime` is public, but require malice from the user to be directly used (since it is not declared at file scope in the public header file).

(and you might even use `namespace` tricks)

Notice that the compiler cannot prevent undefined behavior, such as a pointer getting accidentally the address of a `static` variable.

And on Linux, you could even play some [visibility](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) tricks.

---

With [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) *specifically* you might try to have two names to the same global memory location (using [assembler labels](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Asm-Labels.html)), e.g. in your public header

```
extern volatile const double simTime_public asm ("myrealsimTime");
```

and in some implementation file you'll have instead

```
double simTime_private asm("myrealsimTime");
```

Of course you are abusing the compiler and the linker when playing such tricks.

(and obviously you could mix both approaches).